# Executing a java class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java project in Eclipse which was written by some other developer. I am very new to Java and have made some modifications in the source code. Now i want to test the code by executing it in eclipse. How can I create a main class and execute the modified code.
Following is the class file which I want to run

```
public class Bio_Verify extends AbstractOutboundServiceProvider
{

  public static String EndPointURL = null;
  public static String ApiKey = null;
  public static String Version = null;
  public static String EntityId = null;
  public static String requestId = null;
  public static String EncryptionKey = null;
  public static String SignatureKey = null;
  public static String SignAlgorithm = null;

  public String requestData = null;
  public String requestXML = null;
  public String response = null;;
  public String errorMsg;

  public void preprocess(IUsbMessage inputMsg)
  {
    LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: preprocess():: inside preprocess");
    LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: executeOutboundRequest():: START");
  }

  public IUsbMessage executeOutboundRequest(String inputMsg)
  {
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      String resolution     = null;
      String key            = null;
      String criteria       = null;
      String position       = null;
      String format         = null;
      String data           = null;
      String intent         = null;
      String resBodyXML     = null;
      String outputXMLMsg   = null;
      String[] responseMsg  = new String[2];
      IUsbMessage outMsg    = null;

      Verify verify                         = new Verify();
      Fingerprint fingerprint           = new Fingerprint();


      requestData = "CN01473|cif|UNKNOWN_FINGER|508|BMP|Qk12WeoAAAA=|verify";

      //Forming requestId for Bio
      Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();  
      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");  
      requestId = dateFormat.format(date);

      EndPointURL = OutboundConstants.Bio_Endpoint;    
      ApiKey = OutboundConstants.ApiKey; 
      Version = OutboundConstants.Version;
      EntityId = OutboundConstants.EntityId;
      EncryptionKey = OutboundConstants.EncryptionKey;
      SignAlgorithm = OutboundConstants.SignAlgorithm;
      SignatureKey = OutboundConstants.SignatureKey;

      LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: executeOutboundRequest():: Bio_Endpoint URL is " + EndPointURL);
      LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: executeOutboundRequest():: Api Key is " + ApiKey);
      LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: executeOutboundRequest():: Version is " + Version);
      LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: executeOutboundRequest():: EntityId is " + EntityId);
      LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: executeOutboundRequest():: EncryptionKey is " + EncryptionKey);
      LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: executeOutboundRequest():: SignatureKey is " + SignatureKey);
      LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: executeOutboundRequest():: SignAlgorithm is " + SignAlgorithm);
      LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: executeOutboundRequest():: Request Id is " + requestId);
      //Extraction data from the request XML
      for(i=0;i<7;i++){
          int x = requestData.indexOf("|");
          int y = requestData.length();
          if(i==0){
              key = requestData.substring(0, x);
              LogManager.logDebug("Key: "+key);
              requestData = requestData.substring(x+1,y);
          }
          if(i==1){
              criteria = requestData.substring(0, x);
              LogManager.logDebug("Criteria: "+criteria);
              requestData = requestData.substring(x+1,y);
          }
          if(i==2){
              position = requestData.substring(0, x);
              LogManager.logDebug("Position: "+position);
              requestData = requestData.substring(x+1,y);
          }
          if(i==3){
              format = requestData.substring(0, x);
              LogManager.logDebug("Format: "+format);
              requestData = requestData.substring(x+1,y);
          }
          if(i==4){
              resolution = requestData.substring(0, x);
              LogManager.logDebug("Resolution: "+resolution);
              requestData = requestData.substring(x+1,y);
          }
          if(i==5){
              data = requestData.substring(0, x);
              requestData = requestData.substring(x+1,y);
          }
          if(i==6){
              intent = requestData;
              LogManager.logDebug("Intent: "+intent);
          }
      }

      FingerprintImage fingerprintimage     = new FingerprintImage(format,resolution,data);
      fingerprint.image         = fingerprintimage; 
      fingerprint.position      = position;

      responseMsg = verify.verify(key, criteria, fingerprint, intent);

      this.errorMsg = responseMsg[0];
      this.response = responseMsg[1];
      LogManager.logDebug("Back in bio verify - array element1"+this.errorMsg);
      LogManager.logDebug("Back in bio verify - array element2"+this.response);

      outMsg = UsbMessageFactory.createUbusMessage();
      outMsg.setMsgType("XML");
      outMsg.setMsgSubType("FIXML");

      LogManager.logDebug("Bio: executeOutboundRequest():: errorMsg=" + errorMsg);
      if (errorMsg.toString().trim().length() > 0)
      {
          LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: executeOutboundRequest():: Inside FAILURE");
          outMsg.setBackEndTranStatus("FAILURE");
          outMsg.setErrMsgFlg(1);
          outMsg.setPayload(new Object[] { new CIFatalException(errorMsg.toString()) });
      }
      else
    {
      LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: executeOutboundRequest():: Inside SUCCESS");
      outMsg.setBackEndTranStatus("SUCCESS");
      outMsg.setErrMsgFlg(0);

      resBodyXML = this.response.toString();

      LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: executeOutboundRequest():: outputXMLMsg XML:" + outputXMLMsg);
      outMsg.setPayload(new Object[] { outputXMLMsg });
    }
    LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: executeOutboundRequest():: outMsg:" + outMsg);
    LogManager.logDebug("Bio_Verify: executeOutboundRequest():: END");

    return outMsg;
  }
```

Comment: Have you got idea from my answer

Comment: @DulajKulathunga Yes, you answer helped. Thanks a lot. Really wish to learn Java now as issues keep coming for which I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you follow the steps , this will help to you

There are  6 steps are below added ( I think you will get idea how to archive your problem )

**1.Right click inside package and you can see `CLASS` then it will pop up this attached window**

[image]

**2. Insight Main method you can crate some object like I have created and pass parameter what you want (You just understand what method you have to call )**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have to write main function into Bio_Verify class. 
main function is boot function. 
So if you write main function, you can execute this class.

ex)

```
public class BioVerify extends AbstractOutboundServiceProvider {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO: Write a code....
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

write the main function below to the code and create object for BIO_verify class and it's function